# Build path entry is missing: /src/test/java

Tags: java, eclipse

While running my java project on Eclipse Luna, I have some errors due to which I suppose related to this problem.I right click on the project, choose properties --> java build path --> source, I see a warning at the top:

[image]

And it seems that I have forgotten to add this package at the beginning of my project.I want to add it now, but I cannot do it via "Add Folder" button.When I press "Add Folder" button, a window appears like this one:

[image]

However, I believe I should add it under "Java Resources" on the tree:

[image]

How can I modify this?
Thanks for any help..

Comment: Just remove it from the build path, if you don't have any tests in src/test/.

Comment: I have a test class under src/main/java.Then, I don't need to add this path. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`src/test/java` is just maven's default entry for any test classes. If you have (or plan to have) test classes, you can create a new folder structure `test/java` below your `src` folder and afterwards select it in the dialog you've shown. If you don't plan to have any test classes, you can safely remove the entry from the build path.

Comment: I removed it.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @oddly: Since you have test classes you might want to create the folder instead to comply with the default project structure. Makes things easier in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to add missing src/test/java folder to the maven project in Eclipse**

1) Create a folder test/java  under src folder
2) Right click on the project and choose Maven --> Update Project --> choose for Force update of Snapshot/Releases  and click ok.  Now  test folder should appear as src/test/java in Eclipse  project explorer